# How change dpi in jsPDF html method?

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

I have figma design 2380х3368.
So, I create pdf with such parameters:

```
const doc = new jsPDF({orientation: 'portrait',unit: 'px', userUnit: 300, format: [2780, 3368]});
```

and:

```
doc.html(pageTemplate.querySelector('html'), {
                        callback: function(doc) {
                            
                            doc.save('pdf-template.pdf');
                        },
                        margin: [0,0,0,0],
});
```

But this size is too big for printing pdf. I want dpi 300, so it would be ok, but I can't find where to put this in jsPDF